# ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() is not working

Tags: c#, combobox, selecteditem

```
String cmbvalue = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
if (cmbvalue == "Income")
{
    curvalu = int.Parse(txtbalance.Text);
    finalvalu = curvalu + int.Parse(txtIncomeExpense.Text);
    MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO IncomeGenerator (Income, Date, Balance, Description) VALUES ('" + txtIncomeExpense.Text + "', '" + Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text) + "' , " + finalvalu +  " ,  '" + txtDescription.Text + "')", sqlCon);
    sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlCon.Close();
}
else if (cmbvalue == "Expenses")
{
    SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO IncomeGenerator (Expense, Date, Description) VALUES ('" + txtIncomeExpense.Text + "', '" + Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text) + "' , '" + txtDescription.Text + "')", sqlCon);
    sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlCon.Close();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Sorry Wrong Input Selected");
}
```

All this is done inside a submit button. can someone help me y its not going to the first statement. even when i select the correct Income ComboBox item. meanwhile the ComboBox style is DropDownList.

Can someone guide me please?

Comment: Please dont shout in your questions.

Comment: I HAVE SORTED OUT. THANKS A LOT...

Comment: What was the solution? Please post the answer so that it can help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
string balance = cmbBalance.SelectedItem.Text;
switch(balance.tolower())
{
   case "income":
    //your code
    break;
   case "expenses":
    //your code
    break;
   default:
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do a `MessageBox.Show` in a server side component.

You'll have to do

```
Response.Write(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

to send it down to the client.  Or, use your debugger to analyze the value.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
if (String.Equals(value, "..", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    // ...
}
```

Also use:

```
int balance;
if (Int32.TryParse(txtBalance.Text, out balance)
{
    // use balance variable
}
else
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Wrong input! So on..");
}
```